# How to design REST API to export data necessary for clients to show them as a single report

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rest

Essentially, clients have a requirement to show this Report view for a particular `user`. Currently, when clients land on this page, they have to make multiple network calls(50-100) in order to get the data necessary to display in the report.

As a solution, I am looking to design a single REST API endpoint that relies on the single Query object that is responsible for querying multiple tables and complicated joins to send a JSON object as a response so the client does not have to make multiple network calls.

Any suggestion on how can I design this workflow?

Comment: what do you mean by network call here? how are you fetching data from db in the current design.

Answer (score 1):

REST API would be a better option to handle the multiple requests. Design the api to expect the request data in query params with required filters and checks. If you are making 50-100 calls in current state then the API needs to interact with multiple tables and if data is huge then user experience can be affected as page load could delay.

Refine this API in one of possible two ways which i can suggest:

- Design the data which is required to load the user landing page and using any scheduler service have this data ready, so this minimizes the queries to be executed on the fly, if data is not that realtime then use caching to resolve this.
- Implement lazy loading for better experience if your page design can afford it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say to have this data ready, do you mean to have something like a materialized view table? or a cache table?

Comment: @webgoesviral materialized view table if your data is dynamic and cache in case data is static. mostly should be materialized in your case based on description.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

1. On the client side build a JSON object string with the parameters and url-encode it;
2. Call your URL (HTTP/GET) with the parameters' object string as a querystring;
   `https://your-baseurl/your-endpoint?p={...}`
3. On the server side parse the querystring;
4. Connect to Postgresql;
5. Prepare and run your complex parameterized SQL query that returns JSON (presumably a JSON array of key-value pair objects) with parameter values taken from the parsed querystring. There are numerous examples on SO how to do this;
6. To protect against SQLi do **not** use SQL text replacement, only prepared statements;
7. Place the result of the query in the response.

Postgresql will do all the heavy lifting in a single query - no matter how complex - w/o any data marshalling there and back.

So the API would be HTTP/GET with a single JSON parameter, response `Content-Type: application/json` representing an array of key-value pairs. Success/failure - via HTTP response status codes 200 or 40X.